# How do I change the graphics of a panel each time a listener executes?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, listener, panel

I am trying to change the color of the dots ive made AFTER the mouse is pressed. So ideally, you would be continuously drawing randomly colored dots while the program is running. Cant seem to figure this out because if i try to reference the graphics "page" in the listeners, it isnt recognized. If I put the random color line in the graphics constructor, then the program runs with one random color and doesnt change for each dot.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DotsPanel extends JPanel {
    private final int SIZE = 6; // radius of each dot
    Random rand = new Random();
    private ArrayList<Point> pointList;
    Color randomColor = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));

    public DotsPanel() {
        pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();

        addMouseListener(new DotsListener());
        addMouseMotionListener(new DotsListener());

        setBackground(Color.black);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        for (Point spot : pointList) {
            page.setColor(randomColor);
            page.fillOval(spot.x - SIZE, spot.y - SIZE, SIZE * 2, SIZE * 2);
        }
        page.drawString("Count: " + pointList.size(), 5, 15);
    }

    private class DotsListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            pointList.add(event.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            pointList.add(event.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to associate a dot with a color and this can be done one of two ways:

1. By drawing the dot on a BufferedImage, and having that image painted in the component's painting method (paintComponent of a JPanel), or
2. Drawing all dots and their associated color in the paintComponent method by somehow directly associating a color with a dot, such as with a Map or with a custom object that holds the two together.

In your listener, create your dot and its color, and associate them using whichever technique you desire.

For example, using a `HashMap<Shape, Color>` that associates a Shape (here an Ellipse2D that holds the circle) and a Color, called `shapeColorMap`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RandomDot extends JPanel {
    // size of JPanel
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    // width of dot
    public static final int DOT_WIDTH = 40;
    private Map<Shape, Color> shapeColorMap = new HashMap<>();

    public RandomDot() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        addMouseListener(new MyMouse());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // smooth out jaggies in graphics
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // iterate through the Map getting color and circle
        for (Entry<Shape, Color> entry : shapeColorMap.entrySet()) {
            Color color = entry.getValue();
            Shape shape = entry.getKey();
            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.fill(shape);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // get a random color using HSB
            float multiplier = 0.3f;
            float hue = (float)Math.random();
            float saturation = (float) (multiplier * Math.random() + (1 - multiplier));
            float brightness = (float) (multiplier * Math.random() + (1 - multiplier));
            Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, brightness);

            // create a circle at mouse click
            double x = e.getX() - DOT_WIDTH / 2;
            double y = e.getY() - DOT_WIDTH / 2;
            double w = DOT_WIDTH;
            Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, w);

            // put both into the map
            shapeColorMap.put(circle, color);

            // repaint
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        RandomDot mainPanel = new RandomDot();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RandomDot");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand. I am having trouble referencing anything in the paintComponent method from the listeners. If I create the dots in the listeners how to I associate them with the graphics?

Comment: @TurnerWheat: you put the objects to be draw in some collection, such as an ArrayList or here, a HashMap, and within the paintComponent method, you iterate through this collection, drawing each item. See above for an example